# JavaScriptのPromis.allをforEachで使用したい。

Tags: javascript, 非同期

下記のように並列で関数を実行したいのですが、エラーになります。
`map()`を使用すればエラーは取れるのですが、戻り値を必要としないので `forEach` のような構文が適している思うのですが、別の書方等ないでしょうか?

宜しくお願いします。

```
await Promise.all(articles.forEach((article) => {
      post(article)
    }))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

たとえ処理結果が必要なくとも、mapでPromiseを返してやります。

```
const promises = articles.map(article=>{
   return new Promise(resolve =>{
     post(article)
  ☄  resolve("OK")
   }) 
})
```

これでpromisesはPromiseを返された配列になっています。

あとは、

```
await Promise.all(promises)
//次の処理
```

とすれば、post(article)が全て終わった後に次の処理が進みます

Comment: 分かり易く丁寧に、ありがとうございます。